# Display SignalR message with embedded HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html, signalr

I've begun playing around with SignalR, of course starting with the initial chat hub that I suppose everybody does at one point or another.  I want to modify it so that if the user types in HTML in their message, when it gets displayed it shows rendered HTML as oppose to just the string with HTML tags in it.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMesg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

        if (message === "joined session") {
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + ' ' + encodedMesg + '</strong></li>');
        } else {
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp' + encodedMesg + '</li>');
        }
    };

    $('#message').focus();

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.send("@FullName", "joined session");

        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            chat.server.send("@FullName", $('#message').val());
            $('#message').val("").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

The encodedMesg has "this is <b>bold</b>", but instead of rendering it as HTML, it just shows it as a string.  How can I allow this to render as HTML?

I've tried encoding the < as &lt; and > as &gt; but that didn;t work.  I also tried %3C and %3E but they didn;t work either.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.text` changes the text of an object and intentionally prevents html or scripts from being parsed.

You can get it to parse it by changing the value with `.html`

```
var encodedMesg = $('<div />').html(message);
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it now displays as  [object Object]

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, using your suggestion of just .html(message), I now need to access the value as encodedMesg[0].innerHTML, which does what I want it to do.  Thank you.

Comment: @Wizaerd:  feel free to mark this as the answer then so it can potentially help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

var encodedMsg = $('').text(message).html();

Comment: And why does this work? Please add an explanation for the sake of future readers